# extracting hour value from a DATETIME format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How would I get the hours from a DATETIME format variable.

Example: 2009-08-17 13:00:00

And I just need to get '13'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in php,

```
list($date, $time) = explode(' ', '2009-08-17 13:00:00');
list($hour, $min, $sec) = explode(':', $time);
```

$hour should contain 13.

Comment: Thanks... perfect except you want to explode $time in the second list();

Comment: For a fixed format like this (4-digits, 2-digits, 2-digists etc.) you might as well just use `substr` - as in `$hour = +substr($datetime, 11, 2);`

Answer (score 7):

```
$hour = date("H", strtotime('2009-08-17 13:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function:

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR('2009-08-17 13:00:00');
+-----------------------------+
| hour('2009-08-17 13:00:00') |
+-----------------------------+
|                          13 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Also see the reference manual for all Date and Time functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html